# Issues debugging remotely from VS2013 on a Surface 2

Tags: visual-studio, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, remote-debugging

I have Windows 8.1 with Visual Studio 2013. I'm debugging remotely on a Surface 2. VS is wired via the router, Surface 2 is obviously on WiFi.

Remote debugging seems to work only intermittently with no logical reasoning for when it fails. Sometimes remote tools show that the client connected and debugging starts instantly and the sessions never terminates until I stop debugging. Other times I get the "A remote operation is taking longer than expected" message and the host machine doesn't see the device in the list of available devices.

Answer (score 1):

Issue appears to have been resolved by replacing the router.

Comment: Ha, thanks for this! Have the same problem, but restarting the router does the trick. Not ideal, so I was wondering - which new router did you get? (seriously!)

Comment: D-Link DIR601. I have a feeling that if you flash your router with DD-WRT, that might actually fix the issue too. Haven't tried on mine.

Answer (score 0):

This is common issue for me, too.
A visual studio restart seems to do the trick.
If that doesn't work, restart the Surface 2.

Comment: I restarted absolutely everything including the router and the modem to no avail.

Comment: did you try to reconfigure the remote configuration wizard? Did you recently update visual studio? Did you try re-installing the RD with the latest version?